# Publish ASP.NET Core 1.1 to a Linux based App Service

Tags: asp.net, linux, azure, web-deployment

When I'm trying to publish using `Web Deploy` (Visual Studio 2017 for Windows) to a `Linux` app service hosted in `Azure` the following error occurs:

```
Could not connect to the remote computer ("my-linux-api.scm.azurewebsites.net") using the specified process ("Web Management Service") because the server did not respond. Make sure that the process ("Web Management Service") is started on the remote computer.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_COULD_NOT_CONNECT_TO_REMOTESVC.
The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.
```

The link in the error description seems to refer windows based hosts.
The service is up and running and responds to my request:

[image]

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

There is no Web Deploy on Linux. That's a Windows/IIS thing.
[Push with git instead](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-linux-using-dotnetcore). The `.scm.` service (Kudu) knows how to handle the ASP.NET Core deployment on Linux.